# AFNetworking never completes when run Synchronously

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking, synchronous

Before someone spams the thread telling me its not best practice, there is valid reason for my not using an async method in this case.

I am trying to force my AFNetworking library to run in a synchronous mode for certain method calls (its been factoried).

Here is my (hacked) snippet:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_apiBaseUrl];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil];

    NSDictionary *requestDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"2.0", path, params, [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]] forKeys:@[@"jsonrpc", @"method", @"params", @"id"]];

    NSString *requestBody = [requestDict JSONString];

    NSLog(@"requestBody: %@", requestBody);

    // Set the request body
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        // Do something with the success (never reached)
        successBlock(request, response, JSON);

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        failureBlock(request, response, error, JSON);
    }];

    if (queue == 1) {
        [self.operationArray addObject:operation];
    }
    else {
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
        successBlock(nil, nil, nil);            
        //[operation start];

    }
```

When the method is ran and the queue param forces the method to waitUntilFinished the success block is never reached nor is the next line. If I use the start method it works fine.

Comment: There is no valid reason for ever running synchronous networking on iOS.  If you are using NSOperations, it's pretty easy to use asynchronous networking with them. http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/

Comment: I wonder if you need to call start on operation yourself.